# Get temp of Adeptec raid card CLI

Tags: command-line, temperature

Im struggling to find anywhere the command to check the temp on my `adeptec asr-71065`. Cant find anywhere how to check the temp. Ive tried using sensors but that doesn't seem to show the temp of the card

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the Adaptec RAID Controller software, then you can use `arcconf getconfig` to return some of that information.

```
arcconf getconfig 1 AL
```

This will return all information about controllers, logical drives, physical drives, and flash backup systems on the card, as well as fan, power supply, and temperature status. It's most certainly overkill, but will give you that information.